# Is it possible to use object attributes as a dict keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x

perhaps some more experienced can explain me what’s wrong in my code. After several hours of investigating I’m giving up!
I’m getting from DB a list of objects (Investments). Some of the investments have the same “investment id”.
I want to build a dict with “investment id's” as a keys and investments with the same “investment id” wrapped in list as a values
Here is a dummy code  that emulate the investment class and build the list for test

```
class TestInvestment:
def __init__(self, id: str):
    self.id = id
    self.data = "bla...bla...bla"

def __repr__(self):
    return f"Investment with code {self.id}"

test_investment1 = TestInvestment('RU000A100D89')
test_investment2 = TestInvestment('RU000A100YP2')
dummy_investments = [test_investment1, test_investment2]
```

and here is the function that actually build the dictionary. Getting all unique id's as a set, than creating dict based on this set with empty list as values. On the end appending accordingly the investments to the dict values.

```
def combine_investments(investments: List[TestInvestment]):
    unique_investments_codes = set([investment.id for investment in investments])
    unique_investments_dict = dict.fromkeys(unique_investments_codes, [])
    [unique_investments_dict[investment.id].append(investment) for investment in investments]

    return unique_investments_dict
```

but on the end I’m getting strange result. All investments added to every key.

```
combined_investments = combine_investments(dummy_investments)
[print(item) for item in combined_investments.items()]

('RU000A100D89', [Investment with code RU000A100D89, Investment with code RU000A100YP2])
('RU000A100YP2', [Investment with code RU000A100D89, Investment with code RU000A100YP2])
```

I assume that the problem is somewhere in using the object attributes as a keys in dict. But not sure…
When I’m simply hardcoding the dict with exactly the same content, everything works perfectly!

```
def combine_investments(investments: List[TestInvestment]):
    # unique_investments_codes = set([investment.id for investment in investments])
    # unique_investments_dict = dict.fromkeys(unique_investments_codes, [])
    unique_investments_dict = {'RU000A100D89': [], 'RU000A100YP2': []}
    [unique_investments_dict[investment.id].append(investment) for investment in investments]

    return unique_investments_dict
```

as a result I’m getting what I want!

```
('RU000A100D89', [Investment with code RU000A100D89])
('RU000A100YP2', [Investment with code RU000A100YP2])
```

Can some one guide me what is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the dictionary with `dict.fromkeys(unique_investments_codes, [])` - this creates a dictionary with those keys, where all the values are *that same single list*.

So, as you add to any of the values, you're adding to all of them, as the value of each dictionary key is still just the same single list.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for quick response. I forgot that `.fromkeys()` set the same instance of default value for all keys. Using of following construction fix the problem `unique_investments_dict = {key: [] for key in unique_investments_codes}`

Comment: @DmitryZakharov: Might I suggest not pre-initializing the `dict`'s keys in the first place, and just using a `collections.defaultdict(list)` so your loop can just be `for investment in investments: unique_investments_dict[investment.id].append(investment)`? Without using `collections.defaultdict(list)`, you could use `unique_investments_dict.setdefault(investment.id, []).append(investment)` with equivalent effect (at the minor cost of creating/destroying some empty `dict`s when the key already exists).

Answer (score 1):

I refactored your `combine_investment function`

You can iter on your `investments` list. First create an empty dict. if `investment.id` is not in this dict' keys, create this key with value as a 1-list containing the investment. Else, append it

```py
def combine_investments(investments: List[TestInvestment]):
    unique_investments_dict = {}
    for investment in investments:
        if investment.id not in unique_investments_dict:
            unique_investments_dict[investment.id] = [investment]
        else:
            unique_investments_dict[investment.id].append(investment)
    return unique_investments_dict
```

Comment: Also many thanks for proposal, but I would rather keep the implementation with list comprehension. In case of >100k  "Investments" the comprehension should work faster than for loop with if statement inside.

Comment: @DmitryZakharov: That's not how things work. List comprehensions are faster *at building a `list`*. Using them for side-effects makes them no faster than normal `for` loops, and wastes memory building a big `list` of `None`s only to discard them (and violates the functional design of listcomps; functional constructsshould not have side-effects). The *only* magically fast thing about listcomps is the dedicated bytecode they use to append to the new `list` as they go, and you're not benefiting from that at all.

Comment: By far the fastest solution for the "huge input, at least some repeated keys" case is using `unique_investments_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)` then simplifying the loop to the `else:` case body (when the key doesn't exist, `defaultdict` creates it for you under the hood).